# Compatible data type conversion for CAST and CONVERT in Redshift

Tags: function, amazon-redshift

As per AWS documentation, list of supported data types for both CAST and CONVERT functions, points to same list (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html).

However, I couldn't find any explicit mention of when to use CAST and when CONVERT.

Also, CONVERT didn't worked for me when converting varchar to date/timestamp

```
select convert(date,'2019-12-25')
```

while CAST, as expected, worked just fine

```
select cast('2019-12-25' as date)
```

It might be obvious but I am looking for some documentation to provide supported list for each CONVERT and CAST.

Comment: This might as well be some Redshift bug. For date conversion I would recommend to always use date mask `to_date('2019-12-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: Yeah, to_date adds flexibility to provide a certain date format. BTW do you know how to bring this to AWS notice? In the past, I have raised couple of questions on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ but never got any reply.

Comment: If you have access, you can create ticket there : https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home but responsiveness depends on your support plan. Usually forum is the way to go.